# Remove Wordpress core responsive

Tags: wordpress

Ok so I have just a basic page on here http://basic.louisvillemarketing.net/

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<!-- menu -->
<div style="width:100%;height:25px;background-color:red;">
<div style="width:1000px;margin:0 auto;">
<div id="topmenu">
Headers Page     Links Page     Blockquote Page     UL and OL Page     Image Page
</div><!-- //.topmenu -->
</div><!-- //.row -->
</div><!-- //.container -->
<!-- //menu -->
<!-- footer credit -->
<div style="width:100%;height:25px;background-color:black;">
<div style="width:1000px;margin:0 auto;">
<span style="float:right;color:black;">foot credit here</span>
</div>
</div>
<!-- //footer credit -->
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when you make the screen smaller say under 700 pixels wide the 100% div with the color is not expanding so the content stays in pace but not the background.

If I move this page outside of wordpress it is fine but in wordpress it does the responsive thing .  The theme is a basic theme no @medias.

Comment: Well yea, the div with the 100% is only going to be 100% of the current browser width.. so if you set the width of the div that is 100% to 1000px then it will always be 1000px
try this... width:1000px !important
that should override any other styles as well.

Answer (score 0):

Either use % in width or use @medias and define width for different screen size

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<!-- menu -->
<div style="width:100%;height:25px;background-color:red;">
<div style="width:80%;margin:0 auto;">
<div id="topmenu">
Headers Page     Links Page     Blockquote Page     UL and OL Page     Image Page
</div><!-- //.topmenu -->
</div><!-- //.row -->
</div><!-- //.container -->
<!-- //menu -->
<!-- footer credit -->
<div style="width:100%;height:25px;background-color:black;">
<div style="width:80%;margin:0 auto;">
<span style="float:right;color:black;">foot credit here</span>
</div>
</div>
<!-- //footer credit -->
</body>
</html>
```

Now It should work, i changed the width to percent.

Comment: That is the thing I dont want it to be responsive in any way.  I want the center to always be 1000px no matter the browser size.  I just need the background colors that are suppose to be 100% do the same thing.

Comment: Ok so I have figured it out.  Here is the thing IE will render width:100% correctly no problem.  BUt chrome FF and everything will not so I had to add this to my style sheet.  body tag min-width:1000px; which is the size of the div holding and centering my content.